# How to find dynamically the depth of a network in Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolution, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was looking for an automatic way to decide how many layers should I apply to my network depends on data and computer configuration. I searched in web, but I could not find anything. Maybe my keywords or looking ways are wrong.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't think that there's (currently) a one-size-fits-all solution for that. E. g. compare [Krizhevsky's](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/imagenet.pdf) convolutional net with [GoogLeNet](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842). Both deal with the same ImageNet dataset, but Krizhevsky's net does so with 7 layers while GoogLeNet uses 22 (or more, depending on how you count).

Comment: It sure would be nice...unfortunately, finding what configuration works is about half the problem.  Most of the other half is figuring out your data...and getting enough of it.  If you want a rule of thumb, take your problem and use a known network design that closest matches your problem.  If it's small black and white image, try a couple of MNIST nets.  Small colour images, try CIFAR.  Bigger colour images, try one of the many imagenet networks that people share.  Next step is to mod it to suit your needs...the input/output, the learning rate.  Adjusting filter sizes is tricky...careful!

Answer (score 1):

The number of layers, or depth, of a neural network is one of its *hyperparameters*.

This means that it is a quantity that can not be learned from the data, but you should choose it **before** trying to fit your dataset. According to [Bengio](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533),

> We define a hyper-
>   parameter for a learning algorithm A as a variable to
>   be set prior to the actual application of A to the data,
>   one that is not directly selected by the learning algo-
>   rithm itself.

There are three main approaches to find out the optimal value for an hyperparameter. The first two are well explained in the paper I linked.

- Manual search. Using well-known black magic, the researcher choose the optimal value through try-and-error.
- Automatic search. The researcher relies on an automated routine in order to speed up the search.
- [Bayesian optimization](https://github.com/HIPS/Spearmint).

More specifically, adding more layers to a deep neural network is likely to improve the performance (reduce generalization error), up to a certain number when it overfits the training data.

So, in practice, you should train your ConvNet with, say, 4 layers, try adding one hidden layer and train again, until you see some overfitting. Of course, some strong regularization techniques (such as **dropout**) is required.